# Description of the set of prime ideals of the $R/m^2$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $m\subseteq R$ be a maximal ideal. 
Can you describe the set of prime ideals of the  $R/m^2$. Are they all maximal ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$m/m^2$ is a maximal ideal of $R/m^2$, and it is nilpotent; it is therefore the nilradical, and being prime, is the only prime ideal of $R/m^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Prime $\rm\ P = I + m^2\supset m^2\ \Rightarrow\ P\supset m\ \Rightarrow\ P = m\ $ since $\rm\ m\ $ is maximal.